# C# MySQL Ошибка при повторном подключение к серверу после первой ошибки подключения MySqlException: "No available server found."

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-code, mysqlconnector

UPD!

Я провёл радикальный тест, исключив все возможные риски, и получил ошибку! Я глуп или лыжи не едут? (Пробовал ли я с двумя разными локальными переменными? Да, то же самое)

[image: Весь исполняемый код теста]

### END UPD

Вообщем потребовалось сделать небольшое приложение с базой данных на своём сервере. В процессе отладки обнаружился интересный баг, сходил в гугл, на dev.mysql.com, даже в MSDN заглянул, теперь призываю мудрейших =)

Последовательность действий приводящая к ошибке:

1. Ввести неверные данные в строке подключения (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.")
2. Ввести правильные данные после повторного запроса не закрывая программу и повторить попытку подключения (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "No available server found.") (Выскакивает моментально при любом количестве попыток)

! Один раз поймал nullReference на коллбэке в функции DatabaseOperateAsync, но повторить "успех" не получилось, может это возникло из-за отладки

Пытался перед началом переподключения удалять MySqlConnection через .Dispose(), пытался менять место ошибки в строке подключения -- результат всегда один.

Помогает только перезапуск приложения

Form1 (Основная форма, точка входа)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;


namespace Aurora_DB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            this.GotFocus += Form1_GotFocus;
            DatabaseManager.InterfaceLockEvent += DatabaseManager_InterfaceLockEvent;
            DatabaseManager.database.StateChange += Database_StateChange;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Database_StateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (form.GetType().ToString() == "Aurora_DB.databaseProcessingForm")
                    form.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            databaseSourceSelectionForm dtbssf = new databaseSourceSelectionForm();
            ref databaseSourceSelectionForm.ConnectionInformationStructure conn = ref databaseSourceSelectionForm.connectionInformation;


        RetryOperation:
            AddInFunc.FormControl.ShowInParentCenterAsDialog(this, dtbssf);

            if (dtbssf.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            try
            {
                DatabaseManager.Connect(server:     conn.adress, 
                                        port:       conn.port, 
                                        username:   conn.name, 
                                        password:   conn.password);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            if (!(DatabaseManager.database.State == ConnectionState.Open) && (dtbssf.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)) goto RetryOperation;
            if (dtbssf.DialogResult == DialogResult.Abort)
                Application.Exit();

            DatabaseManager.Disconnect();
        }

        private void DatabaseManager_InterfaceLockEvent(bool isLocked)
        {
            this.Enabled = !isLocked;
            if (isLocked)
            {
                databaseProcessingForm loginform = new databaseProcessingForm();
                loginform.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width/2 - loginform.Width/2, this.Location.Y + this.Height / 2 - loginform.Height / 2);
                loginform.Show();
            }

            if (!isLocked)
                databaseProcessingForm.allFormDispose();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatabaseManager.Disconnect();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader record = DatabaseManager.Request("SELECT Id FROM auroraschema.parts;"))
            {
                if (record == null) return;
                if (record.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(record.GetInt32(0).ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Table empty!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseManager (статичный класс для группировке функций связанных с базой данных) (ошибка возникает здесь в методе DatabaseOperateAsync, внутри try/catch)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Aurora_DB
{
    static class DatabaseManager
    {
        public static MySqlConnection database = new MySqlConnection();


        public delegate void voidCallbackDelegate();

        public delegate void interfaceLockEventHandler(bool isLocked);
        private static bool isApplicationLocked = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Сообщает обработчикам о необходимости блокировки(isLocked:true)/разблокировки(isLocked:false) элементов управления на время ожидания ответа базы данных 
        /// </summary>
        public static event interfaceLockEventHandler InterfaceLockEvent;

        /// <summary>
        /// Открывает асинхронное подключение к базе данных с заданными параметрами,
        /// выводит окно ожидания, сообщая о блокировке/разблокировке через InterfaceLockEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Логин пользователя базы данных</param>
        /// <param name="password">Пароль пользователя базы данных</param>
        /// <param name="server">IP адрес хоста на котором развёрнута база данных</param>
        /// <param name="port">Порт для подключения к базе данных</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Connect(string username, string password, string server, string port)
        {

            //database.Dispose();
            //database = new MySqlConnection();


            database.ConnectionString = string.Format(@"server={0}, {1};
                                                            database=auroraschema; 
                                                            user id={2}; 
                                                            password={3}",

                                                        server, port, username, password);

            return Connect();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Открывает асинхронно подключение к базе данных из пула используя параметры созданного прежде подключения,
        /// выводит окно ожидания, сообщая о блокировке/разблокировке через InterfaceLockEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Connect()
        {
            databaseProcessingForm.processText = "Соединение{0}";
            databaseProcessingForm.processColor = Color.LightGreen;
            DatabaseOperateAsync(database.Open);
            while (isApplicationLocked) { Application.DoEvents(); }
            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Закрывает асинхронно текущее подключение к базе данных сессию убирая его в пул,
        /// выводит окно ожидания, сообщая о блокировке/разблокировке через InterfaceLockEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Disconnect()
        {
            databaseProcessingForm.processText = "Отключение{0}";
            databaseProcessingForm.processColor = Color.IndianRed;
            DatabaseOperateAsync(database.Close);
            while (isApplicationLocked) { Application.DoEvents(); }
            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Отправляет асинхронно запрос в базу данных и возвращает экземпляр MySqlDataReader для доступа к данным,
        /// выводит окно ожидания, сообщая о блокировке/разблокировке через InterfaceLockEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static MySqlDataReader Request(string query)
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, database);
            IAsyncResult result;

            ApplicationLock(true);

            try
            {
                result = command.BeginExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ApplicationLock(false);
                return null;
            }

            while (!result.IsCompleted) { Application.DoEvents(); }
            ApplicationLock(false);
            try
            {
                return command.EndExecuteReader(result);
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                if (e.Message == "")
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Выполняет заданную функцию в другом потоке, вызывая событие блокировки приложения
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operation"></param>
        private static async void DatabaseOperateAsync(voidCallbackDelegate operation)
        {
            ApplicationLock(true);
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => { operation(); });
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(text:ex.Message,caption:"Ошибка подключения",buttons:MessageBoxButtons.OK,icon:MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            ApplicationLock(false);
        }

        private static void ApplicationLock(bool lockStatus)
        {
            isApplicationLocked = lockStatus;
            InterfaceLockEvent.Invoke(lockStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

databaseSourceSelectionForm (Форма ввода данных  подключения)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Aurora_DB
{
    public partial class databaseSourceSelectionForm : Form
    {
        public static ConnectionInformationStructure connectionInformation = new ConnectionInformationStructure();
        public struct ConnectionInformationStructure
        {
            internal string adress, port, name, password;
        }

        public databaseSourceSelectionForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void databaseSourceSelectionForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            netAddressTextBox.Text  = Properties.Settings.Default.lastMasterDatabaseNetAddress;
            netPortTextBox.Text     = Properties.Settings.Default.lastMasterDatabaseNetPort;
            userNameTextBox.Text    = Properties.Settings.Default.lastUserName;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connectionInformation.adress    = netAddressTextBox.Text;
            connectionInformation.port      = netPortTextBox.Text;
            connectionInformation.name      = userNameTextBox.Text;
            connectionInformation.password  = userPasswordTextBox.Text;

            Properties.Settings.Default.lastUserName = userNameTextBox.Text;

            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.lastMasterDatabaseNetAddress    = netAddressTextBox.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.lastMasterDatabaseNetPort       = netPortTextBox.Text;
        }

        private void formCancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы открываете соединение и после этого, наживую пытаетесь его менять и снова открывать. Логично, что оно у вас не рабтает. Попробуйте каждый раз закрывать существующее соединение и создавать новое.

Comment: Хмм, я проверял его состояние на момент повторного открытия, оно всегда равняется Closed(), суть в том, что не помогает даже Disposed и создание нового экзэмпляра и открытие нового подключения в нём

Comment: то есть вы пишете `var connection = new Connection(правильные данные); connection.Open();` и оно не работает? Мне такая проблема неизвестна, я думаю, что вы скорее всего делаете что то не так, чем проблема на стороне SqlConnection

Comment: Да, почти так) У меня есть статическая переменная database, я пробовал следующее: database.Dispose(); database = new connection(); database.ConnectionString = myConnString; database.Open();

Comment: Если получали после этого ошибку, то у вас скорее всего была невалидная строка соединения. Попробуйте вынести 2 строки в статические поля (одно валидное, одно нет), создать 2 подключения и попробовать подключиться в разной очередности.

Comment: Всё 100% в порядке с ней, пол часа сейчас гонял как мог. Вопрос стоит так, если гора не идёт к магамеду, может есть способ самому к ней подойти? Как безопасно проверить правильность учётных данных? Можно ли подключиться без авторизации, проверить возможность этой авторизации и затем выйти и зайти нормально?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106447/discussion-between-tony-sider-and-tym32167).

Comment: Зайдите с правильными пользовательскими данными, а затем сделайте запрос `Select user, password From mysql.user;`, получите список юзеров, который можно использовать для дальнейших проверок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение на самом деле возникает на стороне MySQL/Connector, единственным способом его устранить является перезагрузка приложения использующего его экземпляр. Скорее всего в моём случае это стечение обстоятельств, либо кривая версия одной из библиотек. Если кто-то столкнётся с такой проблемой - вот её решение:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Открывает асинхронное подключение к базе данных с заданными параметрами,
        /// выводит окно ожидания, сообщая о блокировке/разблокировке через InterfaceLockEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="username">Логин пользователя базы данных</param>
        /// <param name="password">Пароль пользователя базы данных</param>
        /// <param name="server">IP адрес хоста на котором развёрнута база данных</param>
        /// <param name="port">Порт для подключения к базе данных</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DialogResult Connect(string username, string password, string server, string port)
        {

            //database.Dispose();
            //database = new MySqlConnection();


            database.ConnectionString = string.Format(@"server={0}, {1};
                                                            database=auroraschema; 
                                                            user id={2}; 
                                                            password={3}",

                                                        server, port, username, password);
            Disconnect();
            return Connect();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Открывает асинхронно подключение к базе данных из пула используя параметры созданного прежде подключения,
        /// выводит окно ожидания, сообщая о блокировке/разблокировке через InterfaceLockEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DialogResult Connect()
        {
            if (!databasePing(databaseSourceSelectionForm.connectionInformation)) return DialogResult.Abort;

            databaseProcessingForm.processText = "Авторизация{0}";
            databaseProcessingForm.processColor = Color.LightGreen;
            DatabaseOperateAsync(database.Open);
            while (isApplicationLocked) { Application.DoEvents(); }

            if (database.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                return DialogResult.OK;
            return DialogResult.Cancel;
        }

        public static bool databasePing(databaseSourceSelectionForm.ConnectionInformationStructure conn)
        {
            databaseProcessingForm.processText = "Подключение{0}";
            databaseProcessingForm.processColor = Color.IndianRed;
            ApplicationLock(true);


            using (System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcp_client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
            {
                Task<bool> pinging = Task.Run(() => {

                    tcp_client.Connect(conn.adress,
                                       int.Parse(conn.port));

                    return tcp_client.Connected;

                });

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
                while (pinging.Status == TaskStatus.Running) { Application.DoEvents(); }

                try
                {
                    if (!pinging.Result) return false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ApplicationLock(false);
                    return false;
                }

                tcp_client.Close();
            }
            ApplicationLock(false);
            return true;
        }
```

Встроенный `MySqlConnection.Ping()` тоже у меня не работает, по этому просто делаем проверку открытием чистого TCP подключения. Если порт недоступен `Socket.Connect()` вызывает ошибку, если всё хорошо, то `bool Socket.Connect()` возвращает `true`

**Итог:**

Алгоритм следующий

- Создаём TCP подключение (ошибка - адресс не верен, true - можно логиниться)
- Закрываем TCP если нашли порт
- Подключаем MySqlConnector по проверенному адресу
- Ожидаем ответа (ошибка в логине и пароле почти не приводит к возникновению описанной проблемы)
- Радуемся жизни!

Можно для полного счастья добавить идею предложенную @Bulson в комментариях, но это требует создания на сервере отдельной общей учётки для проверки строки подключения